# Haskell: Get caller function name

Tags: haskell, reflection

In Haskell, is there a way to get the caller function name?  Of course I could hard-code it, but that turns into a maintenance burden: If someone were to rename the function, nothing is forcing them to rename the hard-coded name.

A contrived example:

```
f1 :: String
f1 = "f1" -- can this be automated?
```

Comment: perhaps with Template Haskell, although I'm not familiar with how to write such code. I'm certain you can't do this without TH.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do this with template Haskell, either. It doesn't have facilities to inspect the splice location. You could use CPP macros to get the file name and line number. Don't think there's anything else close.

Comment: Why do you need a (not *the*) name for the function? Logging?

Comment: I am doing db validation in an API, and want to give a nice error msg which includes the name of the API caller function.

Comment: (Note that it generally is **not** a good idea to expose API function names in error messages, as this poses a security risk.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with GHC's [CallStack](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/GHC-Stack.html#t:CallStack) functionality.

```
import GHC.Stack ( HasCallStack, getCallStack, callStack )

foo :: HasCallStack => String -> String
foo s = let ((name, _):_) = getCallStack callStack
         in s <> ": " <> name

main :: HasCallStack => IO ()
main = putStrLn $ foo "This string is being passed to"
```

Produces output `This string is being passed to: foo`

See my link above for a full description, but basically you can ask to have access to a (partial) call stack in a function by including a `HasCallStack` constraint. Then `callStack` gets a `CallStack`, which is isomorphic to `[(String, SrcLoc)]`, where the first element of each pair is a function name; `getCallStack` converts the abstract `CallStack` type into an actual list of pairs.

(The docs seem to claim that `HasCallStack` constraints can be inferred, but in my very brief experiments that wasn't happening; if I used `callStack` in a function with no signature I was just getting an empty call stack; probably best to explicitly write a signature with a `HasCallStack` constraint)

Comment: With respect to your last point, originally, `HasCallStack` constraints were inferred.  This was changed in response to issue [#11573](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/11573),  The current [GHC documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#hascallstack) documents the correct *two*-step process for solving `HasCallStack`, but the `GHC.Stack` documentation is in error and still refers to the old *three*-step process that included the inference step.

Answer (score 2):

A kernel of an idea: make `f1` be a parameterized thing. This will make it possible to put the code name and the string representing the code name together, to reduce the chances that somebody renames one without the other. So:

```
f1Raw :: String -> String
f1Raw name = name

f1 :: String
f1 = f1Raw "f1"
```

With a bit of Template Haskell hackery, it is likely that you could make an interface `withName :: String -> Q [Decl]` or so that let you write something like this as a shorthand for this pattern:

```
-- f1Raw exactly as before
f1Raw :: String -> String
f1Raw name = name

-- this next line...
$(withName "f1")
-- ...would expand to these two:
-- f1 :: String
-- f1 = f1Raw "f1"
```

The behavior of `withName` would be, roughly:

1. Take the given `String`, append `"Raw"`, and create a `Name` for the corresponding thing in the current module.
2. Use introspection to get the type of the raw thing, check that it starts out `String -> ...`, then strip the `String ->` bit and create a `Decl` that declares `f1 :: ...`.
3. Implement `f1 = f1Raw "f1"` as a second `Decl`.